# How to resolve word wrap text issue in css

Tags: css

I am trying to resolve word wrap text issue but i do not know how to resolve this issue.
In my code i want to avoid like as-assistanceCompany same like for all text with -. It is should be come below new line without -. How do it? If anyone knows Please help to find solution.

CSS:

```
  .content {
    margin: 30px;
    height: 60px; 
    background-color: #ff6666;
    overflow-wrap: break-word; 
    display: inline-grid;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `hyphens: auto;` ?

Comment: @Tom:  I am expecting like do not break the word.So ,If i remove the hyphens, is it work? Some times text is coming without hyphens to the next line like assistanc and last letter e is coming next line

Comment: @sarann can you clarify this?  If you don't want to break words, you'll need to remove the `word-break: break-word` line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the word to wrap to new line, and not hyphenate? If so, this is it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #242b2e;
  color: white;
}

.dahsboard {
  width: 148px;
  height: 148px;
  padding: 6px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  margin: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ff6666;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-grid;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

</head>

<body>
  <divv class="dahsboard">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        Assistance Company assistance Company assistance Company assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceAssistance Company assistance Company assistance Company assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany
        assistanceCompany assistanceCompany666 assistanceAssistance Companyssssss assistance Company assistance Company assistanceCompany assistanceCompany2222 assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceAssistance Company assistance
        Company assistance Company assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceAssistance Company assistance Company assistance Company assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany
        assistanceCompany assistanceAssistance Company assistance Company assistance Company assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceAssistance Company assistance Company assistance Company assistanceCompany
        assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceAssistance Company assistance Company assistance Company assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceAssistance
        Company assistance Company assistance Company assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceAssistance Company assistance Company assistance Company assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceCompany
        assistanceCompany assistanceCompany assistanceassistance Managers assistanceassistance Managers assistanceassistance Managerss assistanceassistance Managers assistanceassistance Managers
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```